# List index out of range in perceptron example

Tags: python, arrays, list, machine-learning

I have this piece of code that aims to change the value of a cell of a 2D array to a 1 or a 0 according to whether or not it is equal to `Iris-versicolor`.

```
for row in data:
    if (row[4] == "Iris-versicolor"):
        row[4] == 1
    else:
        row[4] == 0
```

The issue is that it gives me an error on the line of the if statement saying `"IndexError : list index out of range"`. I understand the error (I think) saying that I'm trying to access a cell that doesn't exist, except that I have checked and my data array does have a 5th column (indexed as 4) and I don't see where else the error can come from.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Mindoo

Edit: Here is a link to the database I'm using.
Its the well known [Iris database](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/bezdekIris.data).

Comment: Is there any more relevant code you can post?

Comment: can you please share your `data` ?

Comment: @23k I don' think so, I could post the code in which I parse the data coming from a .csv file but I checked that nothing went wrong during the parsing by printing out the data array before having the error and everything was as I wanted it.

Comment: If you think that your row has a value at #4, and Python doesn't, she's right and you're wrong. ;-)  Add `print(len(row), repr(row))` before the if, and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: Is row a list or are you aiming to replace 5th item in data

Comment: @DSM Thanks, I was able to notice that I had an "empty" row at the end that had only one cell oddly enough. That one was causing the problem. Post the answer if you want and I'll select it as accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Try to change

```
row[4] == 1
```

to

```
row[4] = 1
```

also with the row[4] = 0

Comment: Nice catch ! I didn't notice that dumb error. Unfortunately it did'nt solve my problem. My error is given on line 2 of the code snippet I provided.

Comment: Have you tried printing all the data before?
`for row in data:
    print row[0]
    print row[1]
    print row[2]
    print row[3]
    print row[4]`

Answer (score 0):

If your data is list of lists

```
for row in data:
    if len(row) >= 4:
        if (row[4] == "Iris-versicolor"):
            row[4] = 1
        else:
            row[4] = 0
```

Checking if row has minimum of 5 elements before accessing it.